# Best Practice to Use SQL Server Table in Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2012, client

can someone please recommend the best practice to use SQL Server Tables on Client Side? (ASP.NET C#)

For example: let's say that I have a table with more that 2 millions rows, then when I do the query in my website it takes too long to respond. So the idea is like loading the tables in client side so that I could query without going to the server for every single query.

I'm not sure is this is possible...or if this can be implemented in other way...

I'm using SQL Sever 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET C#

Thanks,

Comment: Why not implement paging? Grab 50 records or so and let the user click 'next' to grab the next 50 items and so on.

Comment: You don't want your client to have access to your sql server, never. please

Comment: 2 millions rows at once? Did you hear that scream? It Is coming from the father of SQL WHERE clause.

Comment: this is like a campfire horror story

Comment: I would recommend the use of paging - http://raresql.com/2012/07/01/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-using-order-by-offset-and-fetch-next/ 
and to user jquery to send the request with what page you want.

Comment: Not so fast there boys and girls.  Nothing in the question says that 2 million rows are being returned to the client.  For @user1580436, please edit your question to show the query you are running.  Also, if you run this query in SSMS, how long does it take to execute?

Comment: I think in my case, would be good idea to implement as Smith.h.Neil said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't do it. Don't load 2M rows into the client.
2. A number of controls, i.e. Telerik and Infragistics, provide for buffered, paginated and virtual data access. Don't re-invent the wheel.
3. If you must, use Dapper, which by default buffers all data.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the quick answer, I'll get the best of your responds.